# redirecting to merchant's web page from CC Avenue website. PHP

Tags: php, payment, gateway, ccavenue

I have done a payment gateway project and it works perfectly. Payment is properly debited from the user account and credited to company's account. But it is not redirecting to the page in merchant's website which is mentioned in a file ccavResponseHandler.php. Instead it redirects to the home page of the merchant's website. I would like to redirect it to success.php and from the same page I will compose order details from the database and send mail to the client and the company. Here is the code from CC Avenue. I have removed few confidential details from this, but the same is there in my file.

```
 <?php include('Crypto.php')?>    
    <?php    
    error_reporting(0);    
    $workingKey='';     
    $encResponse=$_POST[""];
    $rcvdString=decrypt($encResponse,$workingKey);  
    $order_status="";
    $decryptValues=explode('&', $rcvdString);
    $dataSize=sizeof($decryptValues);

    for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
    {
        $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
        if($i==3)   $order_status=$information[1];
    }

    if($order_status==="Success")
    {
        header('Location:success.php');             
    }
    else if($order_status==="Aborted")
    {   
        header('Location:abort.php');   
    }
    else if($order_status==="Failure")
    {
        header('Location:failure.php');     
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>Security Error. Illegal access detected";    
    }    
    echo "<br><br>";    
    echo "<table cellspacing=4 cellpadding=4>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
    {
        $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
        echo '<tr><td>'.$information[0].'</td><td>'.urldecode($information[1]).'</td></tr>';
    }    
    echo "</table><br>";    
    ?>
```

Here is the landing page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <?php
    echo "Thank you for shopping with us. Your credit card has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why  header('Location:success.php'); won't work but you could try this? The following code should prompt the user with an alert box saying: "Payment was Successful!". Once the user clicks 'OK' on the alert box they should be redirected to success.php.

```
if($order_status==="Success")
{
   echo "<script>window.alert('Payment was Successful!')
   window.location.href='success.php'</script>";             
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all I have a doubt whether it access ccavResponseHandler.php file or not. Because it directly goes to home page of my website after a successful transaction. Unless that URL is mentioned somewhere it will not go automatically. Is there a place in ccAvenue's control panel where we can enter redirect URL?